# Designing web site for Explorer 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

What are the topics we should pay attention while designing web site for Internet Explorer 8? Is there any new standard,we should obey for best appearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With IE8, Microsoft is planning to bring compliance with W3.org web standards. http://www.w3.org/

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/IE-8-On-the-Path-to-Web-Standards-Compliance-ACID-2-Test-Pass-Complete/

So, make sure your site is valid according to web standards. You can validate your site by going to http://jigsaw.w3.org/

Comment: XHTML? I thought IE8 still didn't support the XHTML stuff properly. At the very least, google searching confirms that it doesn't support the proper MIME type.

Comment: IE8 still doesn't support XHTML as far as I know. Passing the ACID2 test does not mean your browser is compliant. I think they have mostly caught up with the CSS2 spec, but are nowhere near following the CSS3 specs.

Answer (score 3):

You should never design a site for a browser, you should design sites using the subset of css/javascript that is supported by everyone.

Granted, if by design for ie8 you mean you will not be supporting 7 or 6, that subset gets alot bigger.

Comment: Absolutely agree and coding for IE8, the current version of the worst browser on the planet, technically, is the worst thing anyone can do to themselves.